# Android Linear Layout of a row of buttons

Tags: android-layout

My application has a row of buttons across the bottom of the screen (a Linear Layout, oriented horizontally), and naturally the buttons all have different labels.  My issue is that some of the labels are 2 lines and some are one, and between that and the fact that layout_height is set to "wrap_content", they're not all the same height, which just looks weird.

Now, without simply pinning all the heights to some value, is there a simple way for me to convince the buttons all to show up the same size? Can I set their heights to fill_parent without making full-screen sized buttons??

Edit: Okay, I apologize, that was a stupid question that I really could've (and did) answer on my own...  I set the button heights to fill_parent and it looks fine.  I probably should've tested THEN posted.  Who knew??

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a table layout inside that linear layout like this

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
Button b = new Button (this);
b.setTextSize(10.0f);
tr.addView(b,47,47);
```

this way the size of button remains same